# Sending Email using live/gmail smtp

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, gmail

I am using C# to send email using SMTP and gmail server.

Below is the code I am using for sending email. I encounter a few errors i.e.

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

```
    public static bool SendEmail(string from, string[] to, string[] cc, string[] bcc, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml, List<Attachment> attachmentList)
    {
        try
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(string.Join(",", to)));

            if (cc != null && cc.Any())
            {
                mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(string.Join(",", cc)));
            }

            if (bcc != null && bcc.Any())
            {
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(string.Join(",", bcc)));
            }

            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

            if (attachmentList != null)
            {
                foreach (var attachment in attachmentList)
                {
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
            }

            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 587; //465
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@email.com", "passsword");
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I use gmail to send email.

Comment: Did you check that the credentials are actually correct?

Comment: Yes the credentials are correct.

Comment: put this line in your code if you provide particular email address and password `smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`

Comment: Login to Gmail and Follow this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and turn it on.

Comment: Do you have 2 factor auth enabled?

Comment: For me your code looks ok, try to check Gmail Inbox you may have mail regarding sign up attempt from unsecured app or any thing else,if you have mail received from gmail then follow instruction and change the setting according to it.

Comment: Is the from address identical to the login address? Otherwise gmail might think you're trying to relay the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false`, so despite the fact you have provided credentials, the application is still trying to use your windows credentials to log into the SMTP. Try the below:

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@email.com", "passsword");
```

`UseDefaultCredentials` needs to be set to `false` **before** you set the new network credentials.

Comment: `UseDefaultCredentials` is by default set to `false`. You have to set it to `true` manually if you actually want to use the default credentials.

Comment: @user1666620, Thank you very much the key here was the placement of the UseDefaltCredentials.

Comment: @Adwaenyth if `UseDefaultCredentials` was set to `false` by default, you wouldn't need to set it to `false` to get the application to work. I know the documentation says otherwise, but it wouldn't be the first the time documentation was wrong. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user1666620 strange since the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: @Adwaenyth the documentation is wrong. You need to explicitly set `UseDefaultCredentials` to false if you want to use something other than your windows credentials. As I edited into my comment, if the default value was false in the first place, then this would not be the most common problem I've seen on SO when it comes to using SmtpClient. Feel free to write an application to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @user1666620 I just did (Console App .Net 4.6.1 VS2015). The debugger shows me the UseDefaultCredentials as `false` after creating a new instance of SmtpClient like the documentation stated and I just sent a mail from my private account to my private account with the correct server credentials... and I highly doubt my private mail server would accept my company credentials.

Comment: @Adwaenyth do you have a reference to UseDefaultCredentials in your code? If so, what happens if you remove it? I've never been able to successfully send an email request to gmail without explicitly setting it to false. Also, how would you explain the OPs issue being solved by setting UseDefaultCredentials to false with no other change?

Comment: @user1666620 I do believe you that OP remedied his issue, otherwise I doubt he would have marked your answer. And no, I don't have any reference to UseDefaultCredentials. I just created the `SmtpClient` instance, created new `NetworkCredentials` and sent the mail - okay not to gmail but my own private mail server, but that shouldn't make any difference since it isn't part of our company's domain. I just would like to know why you both can reproduce it and I can't.

Comment: @Adwaenyth I know this seems like a bit of effort, but can you try testing using a third party SMTP, such as a throwaway gmail or yahoo account? After work will try something similar.

Comment: @user1666620 Not getting an 5.5.1 error via gmail, but currently getting a `net_io_connectionclosed` exception while sending the mail.

Comment: @Adwaenyth that looks like a port error - you using port 587 for gmail and SSL is enabled?

Comment: @user1666620 Guess it had a little delay until it let me send through the less secure app. It did work now though without setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to false (which it was from the start according to the debugger).

Comment: @Adwaenyth I just tested myself - had to download VS Community Edition onto my home laptop, and I'll be damned but it actually worked. Microsoft must have gone and changed something in the past year or two, because this never worked for me before now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your Username and Password are correct and you are still getting the error then it means that **Gmail** has blocked your application.

Try turning it on from here [Grant Access to Less Secure Apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)

[image: Secure App]

Comment: Gmail has the less secure apps as true. So I have that checked but still get the same error :(

Comment: to the downvoter, while this was not what caused the error the OP received, if less secure apps is not enabled you will get the error the OP described.